# it have Warning which "Cannot update a component while rendering to a different component" after finished the auto count down function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I created a `<Backdrop />` component and called in `<App />`

In `<App />`, having a button to call out the `<Backdrop />`. Inside of the `<Backdrop />`, it has a `useEffect` to handle the count down function and render the count. After the count is down to `0`, the `<Backdrop />` will close.

In fact, the modal can close when the count is down to `0`, but it will have a warning that `` Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`Backdrop`). ``

```
const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

return{
 <View>
   <Button onPress={() => setModal(true)}/>
   <Backdrop modal={modal} callback={() => setModal(false)}/>
 </View>
}
```

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (modal) {
      setCount(3);
      const tmp = setInterval(() => {
        setCount(prev => {
          let newCount = --prev;
          if (newCount === 0) {
            callback();
            clearInterval(tmp);
          }
          return newCount;
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [modal]);

return{
 <Modal>
   <Text>{count}</Text>
 </Modal>
}
```

Comment: This happens when a component is rendering while asking a parent component to update, in this case `setCount` returns `newCount` that updates the `Modal` but asks for the parent to close via `setModal`, you need to `setCount` only when `newCount > -1` and wait for a cycle to go to -1 to then close without updating. See @ori-drori solution for more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't update multiple states inside the `useState` updater function. Track the count in another `useEffect`, and close the modal when it reaches 0:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Parent = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  return (
   <div>
     <button onClick={() => setModal(true)}>Show modal</button>
     {modal && <Backdrop onClose={() => setModal(false)} />}
   </div>
  );
}

const Backdrop = ({ onClose }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(3);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(prev => prev - 1);
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (count === 0) onClose();
  });

  return <div>{count}</div>;
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Parent />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```